# How to output the shell script even after all the rules have been finished in `snakemake`?

Tags: snakemake

If I have a snakemake workflow and I already finished all the rules, I want to output the shell  command lines. Is there a way to do this?

I know `-n -p` can output the command lines before the rules have been finished.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to use the option `-F` which tells snakemake to rerun all rules even if targets are already present on the file system.

> --forceall, -F        Force the execution of the selected (or the first)
>                           rule and all rules it is dependent on regardless of
>                           already created output.

Don't forget the `-n` (dry-run) option if you don't want to run your pipeline again and `-p` (print shell commands).